# How to encode json with ISO-8859-1 in java aplication?

Tags: java, json, encoding

I'm using curl to get the content of my Shopify store in a java application:

```
curl --ssl-no-revoke -sb -X GET "myshopiy_url" -H "X-Shopify-Access-Token: token" -H "Accept: application/json;charset=ISO-8859-1"
```

I have tried many alternatives:

```
String destination_name = 
            new String(destination.get("first_name").toString().getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "ISO-8859-1") 
            + " " + 
            new String(destination.get("last_name").toString().getBytes( "ISO-8859-1" ), "ISO-8859-1"); 

String destination_name = 
            new String(destination.get("first_name").toString().getBytes( "UTF-8" ), "ISO-8859-1") 
            + " " + 
            new String(destination.get("last_name").toString().getBytes( "UTF-8" ), "ISO-8859-1"); 

String destination_name = 
            new String(destination.get("first_name").toString().getBytes( "UTF-16" ), "ISO-8859-1") 
            + " " + 
            new String(destination.get("last_name").toString().getBytes( "UTF-16" ), "ISO-8859-1");
```

But i'm always getting wierd characters:

```
Instead of Número, i get NÃºmero, instead of Gonçalves i get GonÃ§alves
```

Another wierd thing is that in my Pc, the characters appear like they should be, but in another Pc they don't, same OS (win 10), same language, etc..

Does anyone has any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: JSON is defined to be UTF-8. If you see `GonÃ§alves`, you received UTF-8 but parsed it as ISO-8859-1. Remove `;charset=` (or if you must, UTF_8`). You're converting a string to bytes back to a string, that's never a good idea.

Comment: I tried to put UTF-8, but it doesn't work: i got CesÃƒÂ¡rio instead of Cesário: `Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8;  String destination_name = new String(destination.get("first_name").toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));`         I have also tried 'byte[] fn=`destination.get("first_name").toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);                        String destination_name =  new String(fn, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`;                                                                   I have also tried remove the charset from the request but it also didn't work.

Comment: _String destination_name = new String(destination.get("first_name").toString().getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))_ this still converts a string to bytes and back again with undefined encodings, you should NEVER write that code. It's clear you don't understand how this works. you can't convert from bytes to characters or vice versa without specifying an encoding, so calling `new String(byteArr)` should be something you'd never do. But you are, which - indicates you might need to take a step back and fully grok what's happening here before continuing to try random stuff and praying.

Comment: It's possible/likely that the data you get is already hosed and thus there's nothing you can do other than send a ticket to whatever gave you this JSON, or if it's you / your company, look at the code that made it.